# Trouble creating a version for 2GP

Tags: package, unlocked-package, 2gp

Following is my sfdx-project.json :

```
{
"packageDirectories": [
    {
        "path": "force-app",
        "default": true
    },
    {
        "path": "package/cad-1003",
        "package": "PackageTest1",
        "versionName": "Version 1.0",
        "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
        "default": false
    }
],
"namespace": "",
"sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
"sourceApiVersion": "50.0",
"packageAliases": {
    "PackageTest1": "0Ho2B000000000BSPP"
}
}
```

Yet, when I run the command : `sfdx force:package:version:create -p PackageTest1 -d package/cad-1003 -k test1234 --wait 10 -v DevHub` I get the error : `ERROR running force:package:version:create:  The --path (-d) value [package/cad-1003], doesn’t match the path value in any packageDirectories specified in sfdx-project.json.`

Can anyone help? Should I be committing the changes on sfdx-project.json to Git?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Obviously version control is very important and recommended in general.  However, you do not have to commit changes to Git (or any other version control) in order to create a package or a package version.

---

The error is telling you exactly your issue:
`The --path (-d) value...doesn't match...`

- In your command you have `-d package/cdd-1243`.  From `sfdx force:package:version:create --help`: the `-d` option is for the "path to directory that contains the contents of the package".
- Your `sfdx-project.json` file has `package/cad-1003` as the value for the `path` to the package.

One (or both) of those needs to be changed to the correct path to the package which you are wanting to version.

---

**EDIT** (after additional info given that directory/folder designations do actually match)

Prepend the `package/cad-1003` in the `path` of your `sfdx-project.json` file with the relative path from where you are entering the command in your project.

E.g., `./package/cad-1003`

I tested locally (I just recently was doing some Trailhead modules on unlocked packages so it was easy to play with), and that worked after I recreated your error.

Also, when doing multiple Trailhead modules, by default, `.\\` is getting prepended when I initially create the package.  So you could possibly also try:
`.\\package\cad-1003`

Comment: I'm so sorry. For the sake of confidentiality, I may have modified a few numbers, but didn't do a good job doing it all across. I made sure to match the package path in both the json file and the statement I run, yet I get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. It's with using backslash in the SFDX Parameter (package/cad-1003).  It should instead be package\cad-1003

Comment: You're running on Windows, I assume.